# Creating group/application/user permissions around mongodb documents

Tags: database-design, nosql, mongodb

I'm trying to find a good way to manage permissions for a high number of mongo documents.

What I want to do:  Apply group/user/and or application permissions to mongo documents.

Idea 1: Use mysql to control the relationship (con's duplication of data, 2 diff systems)

Idea 2: Add metadata to each document (con's: would have to update a ton of doc)

Idea 3: Create another collection to manage the relationship (leaning toward this)

If anyone has a design pattern or any ideas I'd really appreciate it.

I'm dealing with high number of mongo docs (1 million+) and am trying to avoid the situation where I need to update a high number of doc's every time a new group/application/permission is added for a doc or subset of doc's.

Comment: What about role-based permissions?  Wouldn't you avoid the situation described in your last paragraph if you restricted permissions to a particular role or roles?

Comment: Poss.. thing is we aren't using roles and I don't know upfront what the groups/users/applications are.  So I'm trying to design a schema that can support future changes without having to update a ton of docs.  I'm kinda leaning toward having one collection just for permissions and joining on the collection for docs.  https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-extended-reference-pattern